# Creating a workflow to move dates from a submitted form to a public calendar

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Using SharePoint Online (and InfoPath2013 to customize) I've created a form using a normal list which allows employees to request Holiday leave.

[image]

Now I need to create a workflow (preferably using SharePoint Designer) that would trigger when the holiday request is approved and then creates a new "Holiday event" into a separate calendar using the Start Date and End Date that have been specified in the original - something sort of like this:

[image]

Could somebody please give me some step-by-step instructions on how to achieve this (preferably using as much out-of-the-box features as possible and as little customization as possible since as now I'm only interning and I won't probably have the required experience to handle more complex solutions)?

Comment: Please be more specific about your request. What SharePoint are you using? Can you post screenshot of that form? Where did you create form? on calendar list or on some other list?

Comment: I have done it just fine with a sharepoint designer workflow that puts an entry in a calendar where the dates are taken from the form/other list. I cannot go into details because you have been put on hold

Comment: Just an fyi, Infopath has been [deprecated](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/01/31/microsoft-phasing-out-infopath.aspx).  It still has some time before it's dropped, but it's something you should know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a custom workflow in SharePoint Designer for the original list (the one you are checking for approval).  You want to make sure to set the initiation so that the workflow starts when the item is modified.  Use an If Then statement to check whether or not the item has been approved. Using the Actions menu, create a new item in your calendar list if your current item has been approved.  Your statements will be something like this:

If current item:Holiday request equals Approved Then create new item in Holidays Calendar

You can then set field values in the new item, based on values in the fields of your current item.

Sorry, I can't provide screenshots for examples, because I don't have designer installed on this machine currently.